# Extract sub-DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe in Pandas :

```
NaN
1
NaN
452
1175
12
NaN
NaN
NaN
145
125
NaN
1259
2178
2514
1
```

On the other hand I have this other dataframe :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I would like to separate the first one into differents sub-dataframes like this:

```
DataFrame 1:
  1
DataFrame 2:
  452
  1175
  12
DataFrame 3:

DataFrame 4:

DataFrame 5:
  145
  125
DataFrame 6:
  1259
  2178
  2514
  1
```

How can I do that without a loop?

Comment: It's not really clear to me how the input maps on the output.

Comment: Especially the *other dataframe* confuses me. Maybe there's a '5' missing?

Comment: I have to create a sub-dataframe each time that I find a NaN value into the first dataframe and construct it with all the values that I found until the next NaN.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** thanks to [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393164/extract-sub-dataframes/43393492?noredirect=1#comment73848980_43393492) for pointing out that the solution above will not work for DFs/Series with non-numeric indexes. Here is more generic solution:

```
dfs = [x.dropna()
       for x in np.split(df, np.arange(len(df))[df['column'].isnull().values])]
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can do something like this:

**Source DF:**

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
    column
0      NaN
1      1.0
2      NaN
3    452.0
4   1175.0
5     12.0
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9    145.0
10   125.0
11     NaN
12  1259.0
13  2178.0
14  2514.0
15     1.0
```

**Solution:**

```
In [31]: dfs = [x.dropna()
                for x in np.split(df, df.index[df['column'].isnull()].values+1)]

In [32]: dfs[0]
Out[32]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column]
Index: []

In [33]: dfs[1]
Out[33]:
   column
1     1.0

In [34]: dfs[2]
Out[34]:
   column
3   452.0
4  1175.0
5    12.0

In [35]: dfs[3]
Out[35]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column]
Index: []

In [36]: dfs[4]
Out[36]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column]
Index: []

In [37]: dfs[4]
Out[37]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column]
Index: []

In [38]: dfs[5]
Out[38]:
    column
9    145.0
10   125.0

In [39]: dfs[6]
Out[39]:
    column
12  1259.0
13  2178.0
14  2514.0
15     1.0
```

Comment: I obtain this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: I have to remember to use `np.split`.  Also, this relies on the index looking like  `np.arange(len(df))`

Comment: Do I have to transform the Panda's DataFrame into numpy?

Comment: @Ralk, no, it should work with Pandas.DataFrame / Pandas.Series as well

Comment: @Ralk, this error message is correct. DataFrame doesn't have such attribute - do you mean `dtypes`?

Comment: @piRSquared, very good point, thanks a lot! I've added it to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
w = np.append(np.where(np.isnan(df.iloc[:, 0].values))[0], len(df))
splits = {'DataFrame{}'.format(c): df.iloc[i+1:j]
          for c, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(w, w[1:]))}
```

---

Print out `splits` to demonstrate

```
for k, v in splits.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
    print()

DataFrame0
     0
1  1.0

DataFrame1
        0
3   452.0
4  1175.0
5    12.0

DataFrame2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []

DataFrame3
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []

DataFrame4
        0
9   145.0
10  125.0

DataFrame5
         0
12  1259.0
13  2178.0
14  2514.0
15     1.0
```